# using 2 column entries in the same colum

Tags: sql, oracle

I've been tasked with creating a query for our internal company store.  The store manager wants a report of orders with the order number, employee name, their department secretary, the date, the office they're in, the order status, and the order item.

I've got the query running with everything but the order item.  In this particular case the item has 2 attributes, size and color, that are located in the same column (attribute_name) in the item_attribute table.

I'm fairly new to sql in general, and i can't figure out how to pull the size, then color, from that column and combine it with the item ordered into a single column in the query, like (SIZE) (COLOR) (ORDER_ITEM) and it would show "Men's XL Blue T-Shirt" in that column.

I've tried using CASE but all I know about CASE is to do things like

```
CASE 
WHEN x THEN y
ELSE z
END AS ColumnName
```

Here's the code I use for the all the other items they want in the query.

```
    SELECT  ord.ORDER_ID AS ORDER_NUMBER
           ,emp.LASTNAME||', '||emp.FIRSTNAME AS EMPLOYEE
           ,sa.LASTNAME||', '||sa.FIRSTNAME AS STAFF_ASSISTANT
           ,ord.SUBMITTED_DATE AS ORDER_DATE
           ,cou.USE_COUNT AS COUPONS
           ,loc.LOCATION_CODE AS OFFICE
           ,CASE  
              WHEN ord.OTHER_LOCATION_ADDRESS IS NULL THEN 'N/A'
              ELSE RTRIM(ord.OTHER_LOCATION_ADDRESS ||', '|| 
                         ord.OTHER_LOCATION_CITY ||', '|| 
                         ord.OTHER_LOCATION_STATE ||', '|| 
                         ord.OTHER_LOCATION_ZIP, ', ')
             END AS ALTERNATE_LOCATION  
           ,ord.ORDER_STATUS_CODE AS ORDER_STATUS
    FROM ORDERS ord
    LEFT OUTER JOIN EMPLOYEES emp ON emp.EMPNO=ord.EMPNO
    LEFT OUTER JOIN EMPLOYEES sa ON sa.empno=ord.SA_EMPNO
    LEFT OUTER JOIN OFFICE_LOCATION loc ON loc.LOCATION_ID=ord.LOCATION_ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN COUPON_USE cou ON cou.EMPNO=ord.EMPNO
    LEFT OUTER JOIN COUPON_CODES cod ON cou.COUPON_CODE_ID=cod.COUPON_CODE_ID
    --LEFT OUTER JOIN ORDER_ITEMS item ON item.ORDER_ID=ord.ORDER_ID
    --LEFT OUTER JOIN ORDER_ITEM_ATTRIBUTES att ON att.ORDER_ID=ord.ORDER_ID
    --LEFT OUTER JOIN ATTRIBUTE_VALUES val ON val.ATTRIBUTE_ID=att.ATTRIBUTE_ID
    WHERE ord.STORE_ID=22 
        AND cod.COUPON_CODE_ID=161
        AND ord.Order_ID = '43124'
```

Comment: That's a bad design.  if the format is always consistent with respect to spacing, you could use a regular expression to extract.

Comment: Given the sample you show has gender ("Men's"), size ("XL"), color ("Blue"), and item name ("T-shirt") in the ATTRIBUTE_NAME column. Are *all* of the ATTRIBUTE_NAME columns for *all* of the rows in ITEM_ATTRIBUTES formatted exactly this same way? Or are some different? Please **edit your question** using the `edit` button just below the tags and give examples. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will help you because I don't know exactly how that column is formatting the attributes but here are two solutions to try

Option 1: If the column is preformatted to what you need

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(IA.Attribute_Name, ' ', O.OrderItem) AS 'Attribute Order Item'
FROM Orders AS O
JOIN Item_Attribute AS IA ON IA.Id = O.Id
```

Option 2: If you need to format the column before hand

```
DECLARE @AttributeColumn AS VARCHAR(10)
SET @AttributeColumn = 'Mens XL,Blue'

SELECT
    CONCAT(
    SUBSTRING(@AttributeColumn,1,CHARINDEX(',',@AttributeColumn)-1)
    ,' '
    ,SUBSTRING(@AttributeColumn,CHARINDEX(',',@AttributeColumn)+1,LEN(@AttributeColumn))
    ,' '
    ,O.OrderItem) AS 'Attribute Order Item'
FROM Orders AS O
JOIN Item_Attribute AS IA ON IA.Id = O.Id
```

One of these options should produce the results you are looking for

Option 1 is simply concatenating the attribute column with the orderitem column

Option 2 is identifying a delimiter on the attribute column and splitting that column to separate the "Size" and "Color" attributes before concatenating with the orderitem column. I used the @AttributeColumn variable as an example of my guess as to what that column content might look like.

If you could provide us an example of what the column contents looks like for the Attribute column in question that would help.

Comment: Option 2 doesn't work for Oracle, for which the question is tagged clearly.You may remove it.